# making a page as child page of another page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i was finding code for making a page as sub page of  some other page which will be known as parent page

like in mvc www.abc.com/home/photos.aspx  like photo is a sub page of it . if we write it with home page it opens or something like this can any one help  i want to do it in web forms

please give me any idea..........

```
  <input type="button" value="Open a new window" 
         onclick="OpenWindow()" id="Button1" />


  function OpenWindow()
  {
    window.open("NewWindow.aspx","MyWindow","height=450,width=300");
  }
```

it is not what i am finding  like i have two pages i want to open two pages like www.abc.com/firstpage/secondpage.aspx

Comment: You mean more than just folders, right? Can you elaborate?

Comment: yes , like we make a webite and plce two web forms in root but not in folder and plan such a way that if i want to make a page a child of another page or like a page which is placed inside a page or we can say anything with virtual path so that the requested page opens as a child page

Comment: like fb.com/home is a page and fb.com/home/photo is also a page so i was focusing on this photo page as it is not placed in a home folder as home itself is a page

Comment: Please use example.com in your example links.

Answer (score 2):

`example.com/home` is a folder which contains a so called default page, in ASP.NET that would be `Default.aspx`. So you could see the same page calling `example.com/home/Default.aspx`.

`example.com/home/photo` is yet another folder within the home-folder, containing it's own `Default.aspx`. You could also call `example.com/home/photo/Default.aspx`.

What you want are folders and default pages, not "child pages".

Please read this article: [ASP.NET Web Project Folder Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ex526337%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: sir i have sone this way but company wants me to do it with virtual paths or something like this

Comment: so according to you sir it is not possible with virtula path and only possible way to do this is it.............

Comment: Well if they want it, they have to specify it, and not with "or something like this". Virtual Paths would be using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. What you describe is standard web behaviour, no virtuality needed.

Comment: Please, don't call me 'sir'.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Open Window"
    onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com/firstpage/secondpage.aspx')"/>
</form>
```

**[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/L935abrL/32/)**

Or

[Refer this](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-parent.php) .Hope it helps you.

Comment: here this firstpage is a folder or a page

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was asking. Also, in ASP.NET, you cannot define multiple Forms.